# Else statement for all if statements

Tags: javascript

Is this a good approach for creating an else statement for all if statements?

```
function myFunction()
{
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  var c = 6;
  var x = 0;

  if (a > 2)
  {
    // Result 1
  }
  else
  {
    x = x + 1;
  }
  if (b > 3)
  {
    // Result 2
  }
  else
  {
    x = x + 1;
  }
  if (c > 4)
  {
    // Result 3
  }
  else
  {
    x = x + 1;
  }

  if (x >= 3)
  {
    // All results are false
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? The () around all the if statements was a failed attempt to group all the if statements together:

```
function myFunction()
{
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  var c = 6;

  (
    if (a > 2)
    {
      // Result 1
    }

    if (b > 3)
    {
      // Result 2
    }

    if (c > 4)
    {
      // Result 3
    }
  )
  else
  {
    // All results are false
  }
}
```

Comment: well you should not have the `var x` over and over again and there is no syntax like your second solution.... Do you want to only go into the else once or once for each check? I think you want `if () {} else if () {} else if () {} else {}` if only one case can be true. But if all can be true, than the answer depends on if you need each else to fire or not.

Comment: This is one of the uses of the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: `if (x) { } else if(y) {... } else{ }`

Comment: @SamR No, it is not a case for switch

Comment: It depends on whether "result" implies function return, making the three `if` branches mutually exclusive.  The question is unclear on that point.

Comment: @epascarello `switch (true) { case (a > 2): break; case (b > 3): break; default: console.log('"universal else"'); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original logic was somewhat inverted, and this complicated your code a lot.  Your logic is 'count how many times these branches *weren't* taken, and if all (3) of them weren't, do this'.

You should see that the code below is actually similar except that I just set a flag if *any* of the `if` branches are taken, *inside those branches*, so there's no `else` branches, nor any counting going on.

The final action then only happens if none of the previous branches were taken.

```
function myFunction(a, b, c) {
    var actionTaken = false

    if (a > 2) {
         // action 1
         actionTaken = true;
    }

    if (b > 3) {
         // action 2
         actionTaken = true;
    }

    if (c > 4) {
         // action 3
         actionTaken = true;
    }

    if (!actionTaken) {
        // none of the above happened
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
var a = 4;
var b = 5;
var c = 6;
var x = 0;

if (a > 2)
{
  // Result 1
}

if (b > 3)
{
  // Result 2
}

if (c > 4)
{
  // Result 3
}

if (a <= 2 && b <= 3 && c <= 4) // your else
{
}
```

Maybe not the best fix but it certainly works.

Comment: IMHO it's "OK", but it also violates the "don't repeat yourself" principle.

Comment: @Alnitak I get that, and understand that. But if-else and switch won't work.

Comment: indeed they don't, but it's trivial to account for whether any of those earlier branches were taken without having to repeat (or in your case negate) the original predicates.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker I thought of this solution, but what if I have 1000 if statements? Your last if statement has to do all of the previous tests again. Could that be a problem? That's why I introduced the x variable, however that means an else statement for every if statement. I don't know which trade-off is the best.

Comment: Yeah, true, your answer would be better

Comment: Use @Alnitak's answer